# Magento 2.4.0 - Getting Error Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am getting below error while installing Magento 2.4.0 using command line.

`Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster`

[image]

I have run below two commands.

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento240

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install 
    --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento240" 
    --db-host="localhost" 
    --db-name="magento240" 
    --db-user="root" 
    --db-password="root123" 
    --admin-firstname="admin" 
    --admin-lastname="admin" 
    --admin-email="admin@admin.com" 
    --admin-user="admin" 
    --admin-password="admin123" 
    --language="en_US" 
    --currency="USD" 
    --timezone="America/Chicago" 
    --use-rewrites="1" 
    --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Also used below commands.

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install 
    --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento240" 
    --db-host="localhost" 
    --db-name="magento240" 
    --db-user="root" 
    --db-password="root123" 
    --admin-firstname="admin" 
    --admin-lastname="admin" 
    --admin-email="admin@admin.com" 
    --admin-user="admin" 
    --admin-password="admin123" 
    --language="en_US" 
    --currency="USD" 
    --timezone="America/Chicago" 
    --use-rewrites="1" 
    --backend-frontname="admin" 
    --search-engine=mysql

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install 
    --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento240" 
    --db-host="localhost" 
    --db-name="magento240" 
    --db-user="root" 
    --db-password="root123" 
    --admin-firstname="admin" 
    --admin-lastname="admin" 
    --admin-email="admin@admin.com" 
    --admin-user="admin" 
    --admin-password="admin123" 
    --language="en_US" 
    --currency="USD" 
    --timezone="America/Chicago" 
    --use-rewrites="1" 
    --backend-frontname="admin" 
    --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch 
    --elasticsearch-username=elastic 
    --elasticsearch-password=changeme
```

Comment: do you have elasticsearch? with auth enabled?

Comment: No I have tried to install the latest magento version in my locally linux mint.

Comment: Have you fix it?

Comment: By disabling this elastic search module. It's working.

Comment: Also confirmed after adding 80 port connection becomes successful but while running indexing command getting error.

Comment: You can see this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320536/48355

Comment: Try this one in magento 2. It will work https://mageninja.xyz/magento-2-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch-null/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have installed Elasticsearch in my Linux Mint & It's working fine. Here is the steps.

Run the below command to Install Elasticsearch In locally.

Download and install the public signing key :

`wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -`

Installing from the APT repositoryedit

You may need to install the apt-transport-https package on Debian before proceeding :

`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`

Save the repository definition to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list :

`echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list`

You can install the Elasticsearch Debian package with :

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch`

Elasticsearch is not started automatically after installation. How to start and stop Elasticsearch depends on whether your system uses SysV `init` or `systemd` (used by newer distributions).

`ps -p 1`

Running Elasticsearch with SysV `init` : Use the `update-rc.d` command to configure Elasticsearch to start automatically when the system boots up :

`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`

Elasticsearch can be started and stopped using the `service` command :

`sudo -i service elasticsearch start`

`sudo -i service elasticsearch stop`

Configure Apache and Elasticsearch : Set up a proxy (Set up a proxy for Apache 2.4)

Enable mod_proxy as follows :

`a2enmod proxy_http` or `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

Use a text editor to open /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Add the following directive at the top of the file :

`Listen 8080`

Add the following at the bottom of the file :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache :

`service apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`

Verify the proxy works by entering the following command :

For example, if your proxy uses port 8080:

`curl -i http://localhost:8080/_cluster/health`

If curl request success then messages display like below :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 06:05:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 389

{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":50.0}
```

Go to `Admin Panel -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`. Change the settings like below.

`Search Engine : Search Engine7`

`Elasticsearch Server Hostname : localhost`

`Elasticsearch Server Port : 8080`

`Elasticsearch Index Prefix : magento2`

`Enable Elasticsearch HTTP Auth : No`

`Elasticsearch Server Timeout : 15`

Now save the configuration & run below cache clean command.

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Now click on `Test Connection` button.

After successful you will receive `Successful! Test again?` in `Test Connection` button.

Ref : [Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/es-config-apache.html) & [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html)

For More [Click here](https://vrajeshpatel.in/2020/08/23/magento-2-4-0-getting-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch/)

Comment: Elasticsearch Server Hostname : localhost

Elasticsearch Server Port : 9200 worked for me

Comment: saved my day.. thanks

Comment: any suggestion about the same steps in Centos8? thanks

Answer (score 43):

I upgraded my Magento 2.3.5 into 2.4.0 and now facing this error, very annoying to say the least,... I fixed it by disabling the Elastic Search module... injecting this into a Magento "update" is totally un-called for, very frustrating and annoying.

After disabling these, my php /bin/magento setup:upgrade works fine now:

```
php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
```

I thought upgrading into 2.4.0 would make life better, I can't believe there are so many problems just to get into 2.4.0.... don't know what I am walking into, ... I hope my installation that I am about to deploy does not break as a result of so many unwanted modules added into the 2.4.0 update before even trying it yet!...

Comment: I had tried this one also and able to run setup upgrade command but getting error in indexing. So not able to indexing and products are not displayed on front end.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi All, I have found another bug in 2.4 and now reported the problem and also the fix under: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29805

Comment: Hi All, posted another answer to this issue, to overcome the installation (and probably indexing), please have a look and let me know if this resolves your issue. hope it helps.

Comment: I feel you. Magento is giving me headache every single day. I have never seen such a unprofessional company.

Comment: -1 because it make cause of others error in catalog listing page

Comment: Hi HaFiz, this is an older answer, please scroll below to see my newer answer which is a different way of solving it, at the end of the day, you must have Elastic Search server up and running, this is documented now in Magento-2 and the product would be crippled without it. I hope this helps.

Comment: i used this command but after that rdbms sql error is coming

Comment: This indeed was not to be "pushed" in, and especially as the "required" says no, but by default it tries it, meaning it is required

Comment: With 2.4.2 you have to do `php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions,Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}`

Comment: A Philosophical view : There is a answer below which is accepted as solution, but this answer has the most up votes. why? because devs are lazy and don't want to use their time, brain, energy to install and configure es. Nice

Comment: php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7,Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions}

Answer (score 15):

**The issue is the ElasticSearch config in your command.**

To start the verification, you can run this `curl` command below to validate your ElasticSearch, you can change the host **elasticsearch** to your host.

```
curl elasticsearch:9200
```

These are the issues in your commands:

1º - Don't specify the ElasticSearch host

2º - It's using MySQL which is not supported

3º - It seems to be a generic configuration and not the right one, as your password is *changeme*

Try this command below.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento240" \
--db-host="127.0.0.1" \
--db-name="magento240" \
--db-user="root" \
--db-password="root123" \
--admin-firstname="admin"  \
--admin-lastname="admin"  \
--admin-email="admin@admin.com"  \
--admin-user="admin"  \
--admin-password="admin123"  \
--language="en_US"  \
--currency="USD"  \
--timezone="America/Chicago"  \
--use-rewrites="1"  \
--backend-frontname="admin"  \
--elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch
```

Comment: Does not work either. Still get the error. And `curl elasticsearch:9200` returns **curl: (6) Could not resolve host: elasticsearch; Unknown Error**

Comment: Probably you don't have ElasticSearch installed or you must specify the right address instead of elasticsearch:9200, for example, `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`

Comment: So I need to lease an external elasticsearch server to be able to operate magento 2? Before 2.4.0 it was working without an external server??

Comment: In M2.4 ElasticSearch is required, so you can have it installed in your current server or you can use an external server, the same that you do today with your MySQL.

Comment: Magento is too expensive at this point, I will have a look at shopware.

Answer (score 12):

You need to [install elasticsearch](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html) first if you did not have already.

Then you have to add a `search` object to the ***system -> default -> catalog*** in your **app/etc/env.php** **OR** make the settings in the magento backend accordingly:

```
<?php
return [
   ...
   'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'catalog' => [
                'search' => [
                    'elasticsearch5_server_hostname' => 'localhost',
                    'elasticsearch5_server_port' => '9200',
                    'elasticsearch5_index_prefix' => 'magento2',
                    'elasticsearch5_enable_auth' => '0',
                    'elasticsearch5_server_timeout' => '15',
                    'elasticsearch6_server_hostname' => 'localhost',
                    'elasticsearch6_server_port' => '9200',
                    'elasticsearch6_index_prefix' => 'magento2',
                    'elasticsearch6_enable_auth' => '0',
                    'elasticsearch6_server_timeout' => '15',
                    'elasticsearch7_server_hostname' => 'https://elastic-search-host.com',
                    'elasticsearch7_server_port' => '9200',
                    'elasticsearch7_index_prefix' => 'company_xy_',
                    'elasticsearch7_enable_auth' => '1',
                    'elasticsearch7_server_timeout' => '15',
                    'elasticsearch7_username' => 'xy',
                    'elasticsearch7_password' => 'xy'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
 ...
```

Then execute:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If you are in deploy mode `production`, then additional commands might be necessary, like `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deployment`.

Comment: i would say this is the right answer

Comment: This is the correct solution for those that have elasticsearch installed but not configured. Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add the following line with magento installation commands

**"--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost  --elasticsearch-port=9200"**

Change the values according to your requirement. I have installed it in my local system. This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Run this command

```
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine '' -f
```

Or

Remove Value From Database

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'catalog/search/engine'
```

Answer (score 3):

For Magento2.4, we must configure elasticsearch or disable elasticsearch7,elasticsearch6 and elasticsearch module before magento2 install command.

=> First download and configure elasticsearch in ubuntu

**Download and install elasticsearch**

> `curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -`
>
> `echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list`
>
> `sudo apt update && sudo apt install elasticsearch`

**configure elasticsearch**

1. open elastic configuration file with below command

> sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

2. change or write host name in elasticsearch.yml file.

> network.host: localhost

3.start elasticsearch

```
   sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

check status of elastic search

```
 sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

**Run magento2 install command**

> sudo php bin/magento setup:install
> --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento" --db-user="root" --db-password=root --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --elasticsearch-host=localhost --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0

Answer (score 3):

***5 Easy Steps to resolve this issue.***

**1st Step:** Make sure you Installed Elasticsearch Correctly. (This comment will help you in best installation, - [CLick here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320536) )

**2nd Step** If you installing magento 2.4.x after Elasticsearch then elastic search will get disabled which re-create the same Error - **Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster**

**3rd Step** Reenable and Start Elastic Search using this `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch`
`sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch`

**4th Step** Verify That Elastic search working now - `curl -X GET 'localhost:9200'`

**5th Step** Complete Magento Setup Using -

```sh
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=https://yourdomain.com \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=db name \
--db-user=db user \
--db-password=db pass \
--admin-firstname=first name \
--admin-lastname=last name \
--admin-email=your email id \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=choose admin password \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
--elasticsearch-host="localhost" \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

I recommend to install elastic search before installing magento setup on server.

I hope this will end your search for issue issue solution.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. this is not a solution to disable **Elasticsearch** modules

> php bin/magento module:disable
> {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}

If you disable these modules then you will get out from

> Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch

But it gives you an error on the category listing page.

2. Other solution in the above post is to

Remove value from the database

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'catalog/search/engine'
```

It will also get a ride from Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch error but on product listing page it will not show any product, products will not display on frontend.

**Solution**

You need to re-activate the ElasticSearch modules if you have de-activated them. ElasticSearch is required to run Magento 2.4.
From Magento website: "As of Magento 2.4.0, Elasticsearch 7.6.x is required for all installations."

If you don't want to use Elasticsearch, you need to implement another catalog search solution as MySQL search has been removed, from the 2.4. changelog:

"The MySQL search engine has been removed from Magento 2.4.0 and replaced as the default search engine with Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch provides superior search capabilities as well as catalog performance optimizations. All merchants must have Elasticsearch to install and deploy Magento 2.4.0."

You should have to install Magento 2.4.* with ElasticSearch. Vrajesh Patel and another guide on how to install Magento 2.4.* with Elastic search. Many sites also guide you to configure ElasticsSeach with your Magento.

I am using docker setup for easy installation of ElasticsSearch

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue while installing `Magento 2.4.0` using command line and I have fixed issue to `add elastic search hostname in installation command`

Hostname: `--elasticsearch-host=els235`

`php version should be 7.4 and Elasticsearch version 7.6.x.`

**Example of Magento 2.4.0 installation command:**

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://myproject.com/ \
--db-host=db --db-name=test --db-user=test --db-password=uiOUTYdfghjkdrt \
--admin-firstname=Kirti --admin-lastname=Nariya --admin-email=kirtinariya80@gmail.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--elasticsearch-host=els235
```

**Note:** You can use `elasticsearch-host` as your instance elasticsearch-host.

Comment: Does not work either.

Comment: Please check your php version should be 7.4 and Elasticsearch version 7.6.x.

Comment: Please put that info in your answer, so that I can upvote.

Comment: @Black I have already mention in comment. Did you checked your PHP and  Elasticsearch version ?

Comment: @Black answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging this, I can see that the upgrade script is calling the "ping" function, which is looking for the following:

1. host: (must be "localhost")
2. port: (must be 9200)

Therefore, to overcome the installation at least, I needed to create another Virtual Host on my Apache that listens on localhost:9200. Doing so, the Upgrade script completed successfully.

My installation now works, however, what's been crippled is clicking on any menu item, this is currently returning "no products" despite having more than 9000 in the database... debugging this further, it's clear that Magento is intentionally (or could be a bug in 2.4) crippling the products from showing unless an Elastic Search is installed and gives it the thumbs-up.

I don't like this, but at least to over the installation issue (as reported by the person creating this ticket), you need an active listener (Apache Virtual Host in my case) listening on "localhost:9200". That's the only way.

The listener does not need to have anything inside,... the "ping()" function is only looking for the port to connect, it would then disconnect and continue the installation.

The ping function is located under:

vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/Elasticsearch.php

I posted a previous answer by disabling the ElsasticSearch modules, this was ok, but the system could not pass this stage, so, had to put these back and do the VH:9200, without making any modifications to Magento, the upgrade script worked fine.

I hope this helps.
H

Answer (score 1):

First, check the Elastic Search Version on your machine.

```
curl 'localhost:9200'
```

The output will be like this:

```
{
  "name" : "***********",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "******",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",      //  << ----- version
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

For Elastic Search 6: execute the below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --search-engine=elasticsearch6 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

for Elastic Search 7 (just update the version)

```
php bin/magento setup:install --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

This work for me!
Just stop and start elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by disabled `ElasticSearch` from DB by run `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'catalog/search/engine'` and from Magento CLI `php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was locally upgrading magento from 2.3.6 to 2.4.4. (PHP 8.1, Elasticsearch 7.16) My local environment was Warden on Ubuntu 20.04. To get rid of this error "Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster" (that was popping up during bin/magento setup:upgrade) I had to do two things:

1. manually add "elasticsearch" to node <elasticsearch7_server_hostname> in vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-7/etc/config.xml
2. disable elasticsearch6 and enable elasticsearch7 module

bin/magento module:enable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch7}

bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch6

Hope, that my answer will help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Anybody that see similar issue.
Take care about **--elasticsearch-host** parameter, and maybe you should change it to **--elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1**

Comment: This way works with my installation Magento 2.4.5 on Ubuntu/Nginx
 
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 --elasticsearch-port=9200

Answer (score 0):

Magento is looking for this config in core_config_data
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname in my case:

\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Config::prepareClientOptions

```
        $defaultOptions = [
            'hostname' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('server_hostname'),
            'port' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('server_port'),
            'index' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('index_prefix'),
            'enableAuth' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('enable_auth'),
            'username' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('username'),
            'password' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('password'),
            'timeout' => $this->getElasticsearchConfigData('server_timeout') ? : self::ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install Magento2.4 locally (i.e. in a docker container or xampp) it is a bit frustrating that Magento "checks" if there is an elasticsearch available during install. My elasticsearch is of course not at "localhost" because that is where my Magento2.4 installation is. Thanks to Heider Sati's answer about the ping I realized how to fix this for my local installation.

In the end I installed Magento2.4 without the elastic search modules (as suggested by Heider Sati) and then got a local instance of elasticsearch running but found that Magento would indeed "ping" to localhost for it as soon as I did a setup:upgrade after (re)enabling the elasticsearch modules. I did a search for "localhost" in the 3 elasticsearch modules and changed the hostname to my local elasticsearch ip. For instance in vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-7/etc/config.xml I changed

```
<engine>elasticsearch6</engine>
<elasticsearch6_server_hostname>localhost</elasticsearch6_server_hostname>
```

to

```
<engine>elasticsearch6</engine>
<elasticsearch6_server_hostname>172.17.0.3</elasticsearch6_server_hostname>
```

which is the ip of my local elasticsearch. I did this for all 3 config files (you could even change the port here (which is 9200 by default) and then run setup:upgrade successfully. Magento "pings" for my local elasticsearch and then continues to install the modules. Then you can configure your settings in the backend and you have a locally installed magento instance at localhost that uses your locally installed elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Download **elasticsearch** from this URL https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Then unzip it in windows localhost htdocs folder
please rename the folder to **elasticsearch**

After that open

> htdocs\elasticsearch\bin

and in that find **elasticsearch.bat** file
Right-click on that file and click *Run as administrator*.

Now the command window will open and elasticsearch is now working
Don't close it while you are using all your command you mentioned in other command prompts.

Answer (score 0):

**Expected result:**
Composer should create this project
bin/magento setup:install should install the database

**Binaries that triggered this bug:**
composer create project
bin/magento install

**Result I get:**
Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

**How I fixed it:**
Using docker-network, I was able to analyze one of the 3 networks that the ECE tool creates on your local machine.
It turns out, the docker image:
magento/magento-cloud-docker-elasticsearch:7.7-1.1
is not exposing the port 9200 or Port 9300.
It is possible java binary it is hard coded to 127.0.0.1 or to localhost.

**Experience required to fix this bug:**
experience with java Spring framework YAML files
CentOS operating system,
Network topologies

**Proposed fix:**
In order to expose the port to other docker containers, one must use IP address: 0.0.0.0

**Workaround:**
You can use Elasticsearch container IP address.
For example

php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:install 
--base-url=http://b2b.docker 
--db-host=127.0.0.1:32774 
--db-name=magento2 
--db-user=magento2 
--db-password=magento2 
--admin-firstname=Xavier 
--admin-lastname=Baez 
--admin-email=xavierbaez@gmail.com 
--admin-user=admin 
--admin-password=password 
--language=en_US 
--currency=USD 
--timezone=America/Los_Angeles 
--use-rewrites=1 
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 
--elasticsearch-host=**172.24.0.2** 
--elasticsearch-port=9200 
--elasticsearch-enable-auth=0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to limitation of elasticsearch.

You need to set the vm.max_map_count to 262144

vm.max_map_count=262144

Follow the instruction from this link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install elasticsearch for magento2 and you don't need elasticsearch for search engine you can install this module:

https://github.com/zepgram/module-disable-search-engine/tree/v0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable authentication, otherwise Magento thought elasticsearch is not running.

Edit your config file, e.g. with nano or vim:

```
nano ES_PATH_CONF/elasticsearch.yml
```

Remove the following config:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

Note: You should only remove authentication if your node is not public.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found to this problem was to just run the elastic search instance and leave it running. To do this just go to where you installed elastic search and locate the bin directory (in my case it is C:\xampp\htdocs\elasticsearch-7.13.2\bin) then right-click on the file named elasticsearch.bat and run it as Administrator. This will trigger a console script that will create an instance of the elastic search. Do not close the console window of the running instance, Then try running the command again and you won't get the error. This works for me, you will sometimes also get this error when running "bin/magento setup:upgrade" the solution is the same.

Answer (score 0):

First you can confirm that Elastic Search is installed: service elasticsearch status

If its installed on Port 9200 then check: curl localhost:9200

If not installed then: sudo apt update

Then run the installation: sudo apt install elasticsearch

First, reload the systemd configuration: sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Then, enable the Elasticsearch service with: sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

And finally, after the service is enabled, start Elasticsearch: sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service

If you make changes to configuration files, or need to restart Elasticsearch for any reason, use: sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service

Then made configuration in admin, that may looks like this, enter image description here

Comment: i am getting ob for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. plz advise

Comment: @NagarajuK You can stop the server and start again.Uninstall the elasticsearch and install .

Answer (score 0):

for me this fixed the issue:

1. Check the results of this query: `select * from core_config_data where path ='catalog/search/engine';` . Make sure that in the `value` column you have this `elasticsearch7`. IF the query returns you no results, execute this command: `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine ''`
2. The value of the `Elasticsearch Server Hostname` it was set to `elasticsearch`. I've changed it to localhost , like in the img below:

[image]

I hope these steps will help someone. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward fix I have done for this is to edit the .yml file and define at least one node in the cluster.initial_master_nodes.

For instance:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```

I have found that sometimes there is an issue with initializing the first node and doing this forces elastic search.

After you do this you will want to kill any elasticsearch process and restart it

```
ps aux | grep 'elastic'
```

then run

```
kill -9 [process_id]
```

and then (I am on MacOS and use brew)

```
brew services restart elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname' is set with proper hostname in core_config_data of db table.

For local magento I have set the value to 'localhost'. Please check screenshot for more clarification - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lynIX.png

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
php bin/magento module:disable 

{Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Magento 2.4.6 in a local DEV box with the standard ElasticSearch box setup.

Error during `magento setup:upgrade`:

```
Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Had to run

```
bin/magento setup:install --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="https://m2-develop.ddev.site/" --elasticsearch-port=9201
```

Note: used local URL and port and not localhost.

Before I was able to complete upgrade via `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

If you import a database from a Magento site whose ElasticSearch is installed on a different server, the setup:upgrade command generates an error in your local environment. To fix it, run the following sql query and compare with another magento 2 site of your local server:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%elastic%';
```

For my case, my local setup was *catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname* => **localhost** and *catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port* => **9200**, but the client's database had different settings. So, this error was generated in my environment. After upgrading core_config_data by setting elasticsearch7_server_hostname and elasticsearch7_server_port, my error was fixed.