# Magento 2.4 Installation: In SearchConfig.php line 81: Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2

I am running ElasticSearch6 in my docker files.

if i run http://localhost:9200/ in my browser i get this information.

```
{
"name" : "shakedeal-1",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "X4OkctATTgmlcdLzmtJ4Yg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2018-12-17T21:17:40.758843Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Here are the contents of my docker/elasticSearch/config/elasticSearch.yml  file.

```
---
## Default Elasticsearch configuration from elasticsearch-docker.
## from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/blob/master/build/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
#
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
node.name: "shakedeal-1"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

# minimum_master_nodes need to be explicitly set when bound on a public IP
# set to 1 to allow single node clusters
# Details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17288
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

## Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks
## see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
#
discovery.type: single-node
```

Now if i install my magento2 using CLI command.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url='http://tile500.co.pk/' \
--db-host='mysql' --db-name='Tile500New' --db-user='root' --db-password='tiger' \
--admin-firstname='Magento' --admin-lastname='User' --admin-email='sanaullahAhmad@gmail.com' \
--admin-user='admin' --admin-password='admin123' --language='en_US' \
--currency='USD' --timezone='America/Chicago' --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine='elasticsearch6' --elasticsearch-host='localhost' \
--elasticsearch-port='9200'
```

I get this error

```
[Progress: 601 / 1206]
Installing search configuration...

In SearchConfig.php line 81:
                                                                                          
  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Comment: if you are running elastic search in a seperate container then localhost is the wrong hostname, you need to use the hostname of the ES container.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Its worked. I change the setup: install option to  --elasticsearch-host='es1:9200' and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with @paj solution given in comment to this question.

> if you are running elastic search in a seperate container then
> localhost is the wrong hostname, you need to use the hostname of the
> ES container.

So checked my Docker container.
[image]

As you can see my docker container name for elastic search is "es1", so i changed my Magento2 install command  to

`--elasticsearch-host='es1:9200'`

and it worked for me.

it was  `--elasticsearch-host='localhost'` before and was not working.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered this problem which is really tiring when installing a new `Magento 2.4`.

> I think you have already found the solution but I wanted to share the
> solution for others.

---

<sup>In SearchConfig.php line 81: Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster</sup>

---

This error means that either you don't have `Elasticsearch` installed in your system or the `host` **configuration** which is not correct.

1. check if `Elasticsearch` is installed :

   with example :

   ```
   sudo systemctl status elasticsearch

   //or

   curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'

   //or

   curl -X GET 'http://yourdomaine:9200'
   ```
2. if you find that Elasticsearch is installed, you go directly to step 4, otherwise you go to step 3 then 4
3. `Elasticsearch` installation : [Reference](https://vi-magento.com/cai-dat-magento-2-4-voi-nginx-apache-php-7-3-va-mysql-thong-qua-composer-tren-ubuntu)

   3.1 We must have OpenJDK to make work Elasticsearch

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y
   ```

   3.2 import the Elasticsearch public GPG key

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

   3.3 add the Elasticsearch source to the `sources.list.d` directory, where apt will search for new sources

   ```
   sudo echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
   ```

   3.4 update the packages to read the Elastic source

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

   3.5 install Elasticsearch

   ```
   sudo apt install elasticsearch -y
   ```

   3.6 we configure Elasticsearch host

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
   ```

   uncomment and replace `#network.host: 192.168.0.1` with `network.host: localhost`

   ```
    # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
    #
    # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
    #
    #network.host: 192.168.0.1 //<- **** uncomment this line then replace it with : network.host: localhost
    #
    # Set a custom port for HTTP:
    #
    #http.port: 9200
    #
    # For more information, consult the network module documentation.
   ```

   3.7 We start Elasticsearch

   ```
    sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
    sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch
   ```

   3.8 We check the status

   ```
    sudo systemctl status elasticsearch

    //result : 

    //systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
   ```

   3.9 Working Elastic

   ```
    curl -X GET 'localhost:9200' 

    //Result something like : 
    {
      "name" : "wbfdfrbz",
      "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
      "cluster_uuid" : "_MpzR9k23l-Vy5vzlSQW",
      "version" : {
        "number" : "7.9.0",
        "build_flavor" : "default",
        "build_type" : "deb",
        "build_hash" : "a179a2a7fwq032d6g9361301700902wff217",
        "build_date" : "2020-08-11T21:36:48.204330Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "8.6.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
      },
     "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
    }
   ```

4. Magento command installation

   In step `3.6`, we set the **HOST** value with : **localhost** (`network.host: localhost`) so we will set the same thing for `--elasticsearch-host='localhost'` and `--elasticsearch-port=9200`, we have keep the default port **9200** (`#http.port: 9200`).

   So an example for the Magento CLI installation :

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://yourdomaine.com/" --base-url-secure="http://yourdomaine.com/" --backend-frontname="admin" --session-save="files" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="your-db-name" --db-user="your-db-user" --db-password="your-db-password" --admin-firstname="Amir" --admin-lastname="Admin" --admin-email="amir@domaine.com" --admin-user="amir" --admin-password="Admin123" --language=fr_FR --currency=EUR --timezone=Europe/Paris --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
   ```

Enjoy !

Comment: What is the expected result from CURL if elasticsearch is installed?? I get 401 Authorization required. And why do we need curl, why not just entering the URL in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to how to install the latest magento 2.4 here
https://vi-magento.com/cai-dat-magento-2-4-voi-nginx-apache-php-7-3-va-mysql-thong-qua-composer-tren-ubuntu