# "Could not validate a connection to elasticsearch"

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch

When I install Magento2.4,gettting error like "Could not validate a connection to elasticsearch". I used XAMPP for windows in my localhost. Please help!

Comment: Read this link about setting's file: [network.host: localhost](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320428/magento-2-4-installation-in-searchconfig-php-line-81-could-not-validate-a-conn)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to installing 2.4, you should've read pre-requisites for it. It requires elasticsearch to be installed. Use this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#install-deb) to install it, also upgrade php version to >=4 if you haven't already. Then you'll be good to go hopefully.