# Magento 2 Indexer Error

Tags: magento2

I'm receiving this error:

```
Catalog Search index exception: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver, Argument 2 passed to Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/shop/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

When I run the command
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Any ideas?

Edit:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 
Magento: 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey Nathan,**

You have need to re-activate the **ElasticSearch** modules if you have de-activated them.

> ElasticSearch is required to run Magento 2.4.

**Edit:**

From Magento website: "As of Magento 2.4.0, Elasticsearch 7.6.x is required for all installations."

If you don't want to use Elasticsearch, you need to implement another catalog search solution as MySQL search has been removed, from the 2.4. changelog:

"The MySQL search engine has been removed from Magento 2.4.0 and replaced as the default search engine with Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch provides superior search capabilities as well as catalog performance optimizations. All merchants must have Elasticsearch to install and deploy Magento 2.4.0."

**If this help you out, please do up the vote so it will helpful for others also.**

Thanks,

Munesh

Comment: Thanks! I completly forgot I disabled it as per https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318831/magento-2-4-0-getting-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch

Comment: Oh i see, Happy to see your issue is resolved, Thanks Nathan