# Magento 2.4 installation on local returning elasticsearch error

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.0

I have installed elasticsearch on local (xampp) and on `http://localhost:9200/` is showing it is running.
But when I trying to install magento 2.4 getting elasticsearch error.

Magento installation command -

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="Test" --admin-lastname="Test" --admin-email="test@gamil.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

And getting below error -

```
Installing search configuration...

In SearchConfig.php line 81:

  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

What should I try to install magento 2.4?

Comment: [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318831/magento-2-4-0-getting-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch/320512#320512) is the detailed discussion about Elastic Search.

Comment: @vinaya what version of elastic search you are using?

Answer (score 1):

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="Test" --admin-lastname="Test" --admin-email="test@gamil.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari yes, i also saw that you are pointing to the ES engine with the 'elasticsearch' alias, but i am not sure you actually have it configured this way, try @Dipakk's command, or replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install elasticsearch on local machine

For Windows go through below link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html

For Ubuntu got through below link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

Now again run Magento install command

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento2" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="Test" --admin-lastname="Test" --admin-email="test@gamil.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

Now it will works fine for you