# Magento 2.4.3 : Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, elasticsearch

I am getting this error on a page
[image]
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver, Argument 2 passed to Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

I am not sure how to fix this error ?
any suggestions ?

Comment: any thoughts on this please ?

Answer (score 4):

- First : Try to `rm -rf generated/` then `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to be sure your generated code is the good one.
- If the error persist you might have an issue in your magento installation ? I would recommend to make sure your composer dependencies is up do date with the vendor.
- Quick fix if nothing works try to setup an empty array for the required null parameter and see what happens after compilation ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
i am using magento 2.4.3 though Elastic search is not yet installed.
i have disabled Elasticsearch extensions.
I have debugged with disabling extension one by one to find out exact error.
its related to elasticsearch.

Comment: If you disabled some module that are required by others modules, it might make sense that it's not working. I'm not saying that's what is happening but it might be. What was your error with ES ?

Comment: Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory.

Comment: The above error i am facing.

Comment: This error basically means once again a constructor is called with a missing parameter. Which is usually due to a wrong code (but I assume your code is fine) or a not compiled code then setup di compile does the trick. Eventually try to make sure the ES modules are well activated : `bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7` cause basically the above errors is magento telling you he need elastic.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.
yes i have disabled these Elastic search modules as i don't have elastic search module installed in system.

Comment: couple of things -
1. from which version did you upgrade to 2.4.3 ?
2. ES 7 should be configured as its requirement for 2.4.3 (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/trouble/current-search-engine.html)
3. Amasty modules are in app/code, thus you will not know if they need to be updated or not and likely to fail with no meaningful error log. 
While composer managed packages throw error if appropriate version is not installed used.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow this steps :

1. Confirm the `Elasticsearch` is configured and running properly for magento 2.4.3
2. Try to run this command.

   ```
    php bin/magento cache:clean
    php bin/magento cache:flush
    php bin/magento indexer:reindex
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

    php bin/magento setup:di:compile

    sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
   ```
3. Still It show the error then according to your screenshot, disable all the extension from "`Amasty`" and then check it.
4. Still it not resolve then disable all third party extension first, then enable one by one and debug from where this issues comes.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced same problem & solved as below details:

As per error log `Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver` that meaning the problem in the Search module in Magento 2.4.0 and above required with Elasticsearch. So you will check if your server has Elasticsearch installed [by here ref.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320512/89849) and make sure that your Magento is enabled Elasticsearch modules by run:

`sudo bin/magento module:status`

if disabled then enable it by run:

`sudo bin/magento module:enable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}`

Answer (score 3):

It's Error say must be enable below search engine extension in your magento2.

```
Magento/Elasticsearch6 
Magento/Elasticsearch 
Magento/Elasticsearch7
Magento/InventoryElasticsearch
Magento/AdvancedSearch
```

Also, you can run composer install / update.

Please check using below command your module in enable or not in magento.

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is ***required*** for latest Magento installations, it won't work without it.

You can work towards building your own mysql search after removing search functionality entirely for Magento along with elasticsearch if you do want to remove elasticsearch. If you want to go that route you can follow this blog post - https://www.yireo.com/blog/2020-09-26-removing-search-from-magento2

Also a heads up if you do want to install elasticsearch now, there have been people before reporting issues that the elasticsearch does not work if you install it after installing Magento. So, you might have to disable and then enable the Elasticsearch modules or in the worst case scenerio install the Magento again.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1.** Magento 2.4.3 : Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver

Solution: - This error basically means once again a constructor is called with a missing parameter. Which is usually due to a wrong code (but I assume your code is fine) or a not compiled code then setup di compile does the trick. Eventually try to make sure the ES modules are well activated :Hit This Command

***php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7***

cause basically the above errors is magento telling you he need elastic.

And after that hit this commond

> ***sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ var/cache/;php bin/magento s:up;php bin/magento s:di:c;php bin/magento
> setup:static-content:deploy -f;php bin/magento indexer:reindex;php
> bin/magento c:f;sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/cache/ pub/static
> var/***

**I hope issues has been fixed.**